# Cannnot create Map<String,color> in Processing

Tags: java, dictionary, processing

I cannot create a `Map<String,color>()` with the Processing's primitive type `color`. I tried with `HashMap` and `TreeMap`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;

TreeMap<String,color> myMap = new TreeMap<String,color>();
```

And here is the error message I get at the line where I declare `myMap`:

```
unexpected token:>
```

It is the same error that I get when I try to declare a `Map<String,int>` with a Java primitive type, when Java tells: "dimensions expected after this token", or something like this.

**Question:** Is this the same problem as with `int`? I'm not sure because `color` is a primitive type of Processing, not Java, is it? Does an "autoboxed" equivalent like `Integer` exist for `color` in Processing?

I can't find `color` in the [Processing complete reference](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/).

I already imagined workarounds like `Integer[]` of length 3 but if it wasn't necessary...

Comment: What is `color` here? It should be `Map<String,Integer>` in case of `Map<String,int>`. Collection works only with Object not allowed for primitive.

Comment: There is no such things as `color` primitive in java. Plus, you cannot use a primitive in a generics in Java. `Map<String, int>` will not compile, but `Map<String, Integer>` will. If you want to deal with colors, you might want to check `java.awt.Color`

Comment: @user3218114 @ortis, `color` is supposed to be a **Processing** primitive type, according to its reference doc, but actually it is none other than a simple 32-bit integer (see Swapnil answer below). The comparison with `int` in my post was just to give an example. Finally, I'm working with Processing, not just Java, so that's why I want to use `color` and not `java.awt.Color`. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`color` is a simple Java integer (32-bit). You can just use `Map<String,Integer>` in place of what you're doing.

The [simple Processing doc](http://processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html) actually explicits it:

> they may be specified directly using hexadecimal notation such as `#FFCC00` or `0xFFFFCCOO`